# Package paths with spaces don't work with rosbash?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, bash, roscd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The location of the package I am working in is

```
/host/Users/Mark\ Won/Documents/School\ Work/College/Junior/Junior\ 2nd\ Semester/CSE\ 468/workspace/tutorials
```

I have added the following to my ~/.bashrc

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:/host/Users/Mark\ Won/Documents/School\ Work/College/Junior/Junior\ 2nd\ Semester/CSE\ 468/workspace/
```

However, when I try to run roscd tutorials, I get the following error:

```
bash: cd: /host/Users/MarkWon/Documents/SchoolWork/College/Junior/Junior: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know how to get package paths with spaces in the name to comply with the rosbash suite?

---------UPDATE: I've tried adding the following to my ~/.bashrc, but to no avail:-------

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:"/host/Users/Mark\ Won/Documents/School\ Work/College/Junior/Junior\ 2nd\ Semester/CSE\ 468/workspace/"
```

and

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:"/host/Users/Mark Won/Documents/School Work/College/Junior/Junior 2nd Semester/CSE 468/workspace/"
```

and

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:"\"/host/Users/Mark Won/Documents/School Work/College/Junior/Junior 2nd Semester/CSE 468/workspace/\""
```

and

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:"/host/Users/Mark\\ Won/Documents/School Work/College/Junior/Junior\\ 2nd\\ Semester/CSE\\ 468/workspace/"
```

and

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:/host/Users/Mark\\ Won/Documents/School Work/College/Junior/Junior\\ 2nd\\ Semester/CSE\\ 468/workspace/
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/124906/package-paths-with-spaces-don%27t-work-with-rosbash?/) by [mackorone](https://answers.ros.org/users/11496/mackorone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Paths with spaces need to be enclosed in double quotes (ie: ").

This is more a bash related question than a ROS one. See fi:

- [bash: passing paths with spaces as parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535677/bash-passing-paths-with-spaces-as-parameters)
- [BASH Script to cd to directory with spaces in pathname](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589149/bash-script-to-cd-to-directory-with-spaces-in-pathname)

on stackoverflow.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mackorone](https://answers.ros.org/users/11496/mackorone/) on 2014-01-31**:
I've tried added quotes and taking out the backslash. I've also tried quotes with the backslash. Nothing seems to be working. I think the issue is that I'm not calling the cd command, ROS is. Therefore, I don't have any control over whether or not the path is quoted when cd is called.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-01-31**:
I agree; I don't think rosbash properly support paths with spaces. In general, spaces in path names are *strongly* discouraged on Linux.